# 'develop' does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git

I have edited the last commit in the local repository and would now like to upload it online on branch `develop`. My project is https://github.com/JonkiPro/popcorn/tree/develop

When I use the command

```
git push --force develop
```

receives a message

```
Jonatan@Jonki-PC MINGW64 ~/Documents/GitHub/popcorn (develop)
$ git push --force develop
fatal: 'develop' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: I guess you are trying to push to branch(not master). try `git push origin develop`

Comment: @Priy No guess. The OP said *would now like to upload it online on branch `develop`*.

Answer (score 1):

```
git push --force origin develop
```

Push to the `develop` branch **of the `origin` repository**.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you don't have a local REF for pushing that branch back to the origin.

Try

```
git push origin develop:develop -f
```

This explicitly indicates which branch to push to (and from)

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this solution just incase anyone encounters it.

1) if you are on windows go to cortana and search for credential manager

- credential manager
- Under "Generic Credentials" => SELECT=> git:https://github.com => CLICK REMOVE

2) Open your Github account and delete the repo you are pushing to(don't worry, all your commits will still be around once you push from local)

3) Create a new repo under the same name you called it. Then go back to git bash/terminal.

4) push you work, it should work. happy coding :)